# Can i pull a URL from a mysql database attached to a log in?

Tags: php, sql, database, redirect, authentication

I want to know if i can use a URL in a database attached to a login that when the user logs in the script will read the url redirect to that? Or any other ideas on a simple unique login redirection?

My database is made up of columns ID/username/password/url - obviously i have the connection things sorted just though you wouldnt need to see them ;)

and my code is

```
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){

session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header('Location: '.$row['url']);
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. At login time, just read the URL from the database table and redirect using [header('Location: ...');](http://php.net/header)

Comment: And as a sidenote: Use exit to halt the execution of the script after sending your redirect headers.

Answer (score 1):

With the login fields in your database add a field specifying the url. Now when the person logs in retrieve the URL and then use the following code to redirect to the retrieved url

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

Answer (score 1):

You would not create such a thing in yor database.

You can house a url field in your DB to be used when they login though.

In your PHP script once you have verified the user actually exists and his/her password is correct by getting a result row from the DB (more complex logins would do more of course) you can use something like:

```
header('Location: '.$row['url']);
```

To redirect that user to another page depending upon their logged in status. Though as a tip make sure they are logged using some kind of $_SESSION variable that is set just before you redirect them and has its value checked on the other page.

### Edit

Use of session_register is deprecated: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php

```
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username=".mysql_real_escape_string($myusername)." and password=".mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){

    $_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;
    $_SESSION['mypassword'] = $mypassword;

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        header('Location: '.$row['url']);
        exit(); // As a user above mentions this is actually quite important
    }

}else{
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
```

Take out that end PHP tag, you really don't want it. I think that should work, you might get an SQL error in which case you can probably work out that it's the quotes causing pain and should encapsulate the field values with `'` but I always forget how mysql_real_escape_string escapes so Ima just leave it like that for now.

Comment: How would i write this in if i have a database with id/username/password/url

Comment: $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){

session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header('Location: '.$row['url']);
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}

Comment: @user1493388 Can you edit you original question with this code? Then we can tell you where best to place it.

Comment: @user1493388 Edited my answer, check it out